# Any way to present navigation bar for UIImagePickerController, source type UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera, in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

In iOS 6, I was using the following code to push a `UIImagePickerController`, of source type `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`, and to show its navigation bar. I wanted to show the navigation bar because after taking the image, I'm pushing another VC that allows the user to set some attributes in the database.

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    cameraController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    cameraController.delegate = self;
    cameraController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:cameraController animated:YES completion:NULL];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    cameraController.topViewController.title = @"Add";
    cameraController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    cameraController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

    [cameraController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
}
```

In iOS 7 this code no longer shows the navigation bar. Does anyone know if there's a way to to get the navigation bar back for `UIImagePickerController`, of source type `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`?

Comment: did you find a solution? I faced the same problem :(

Comment: No, not yet. I've shelved this for the moment. It was a hack from day one, so I think I'm going to do the right thing and work with AV Foundation to build my own class that does what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@LeverkusenFan's solution works well. But instead of using a hack such as a run loop, you use the completion handler of presentViewController to achieve that effect.

```
[self presentViewController:cameraController animated:YES completion:^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
    cameraController.topViewController.title = @"Add";
    cameraController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    cameraController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

    [cameraController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
}];
```

In fact a better solution that avoids the weird animation when the navigation bar shows up and which works well when you press the back button on the nav bar is as follows:

In the delegate for the UIImagePickerController implement the following function.

```
- (void) navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (navigationController == self.cameraController && navigationController.viewControllers.count == 1) {
        // When showing the ImagePicker update the status bar and nav bar properties.
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

        navigationController.topViewController.title = self.cameraTitle;
        navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
        navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
        [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    }
}
```

This function will get called when the ImagePicker is shown and we only make the changes for the rootViewController of the ImagePicker (i.e. the camera screen).

Comment: This does work, and pretty well. The only issue is that the controls at the top of the UIImagePicker are obscured by the navigation bar. Thanks!

Comment: That is true. You have to use custom controls. I have cameraController.showControls = false and in my custom controls, I leave a gap for the navigation bar.

Answer (score 5):

Guess what? When imagePicker presents, it's automatic set to hidden....
All you need to do is setHidden:NO in next runloop. Like:

```
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
[self performSelector:@selector(showNavigationBar:) withObject:imagePicker afterDelay:0];

- (void)showNavigationBar:(UIImagePickerController*)imagePicker {
    [imagePicker setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
}
```